# vtkActor2D not visible when added to vtkImageViewer on Windows

Tags: python, vtk

I am using vtkImageViewer class to visualize different planes in a 3D volume. Then I like to overlay a vertical and a horizontal line to mark the current mouse position.
I use the following code to add a vtkActor2D to the viewer:

```
    imageViewer = vtk.vtkImageViewer()        
    ...
    line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    line.SetResolution(20)
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper2D()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(line.GetOutputPort())
    actor = vtk.vtkActor2D()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    imageViewer.GetRenderer().AddActor2D(actor)
    ...
    line.SetPoint1(x,0.0,0.0)
    line.SetPoint2(x,y,0.0)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(color)
    actor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0.75)
    ...
    imageViewer.Render()
```

On Mac OS X it works as expected, but when I try on my Windows machine the line does not show at all.

Update:
If I change to vtkActor instead the actors are rendered behind the imageViewer, how do I bring a vtkActor to the foreground?

```
    imageViewer = vtk.vtkImageViewer()        
    ...
    line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    line.SetResolution(20)
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(line.GetOutputPort())
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    imageViewer.GetRenderer().AddActor(actor)
    ...
    line.SetPoint1(x,0.0,0.0)
    line.SetPoint2(x,y,0.0)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(color)
    actor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0.75)
    ...
    imageViewer.Render()
```